# xpath - get value of sibling of node if node contains text

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML structure:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <a xmlns="#">
             <b>
                <c>
                   <d>dd</d>
                   <e>ee</e>
                   <f>ff</f>
                   <g>gg</g>
                </c> 
                <c>
                   <d>ddd</d>
                   <e>eee</e>
                   <f>fff</f>
                   <g>ggg</g>
                </c> 
                <c>
                   <d>dddd</d>
                   <e>eeee</e>
                   <f>ffff</f>
                   <g>gggg</g>
                </c>  
             </b>
       </a>
     </soap:Envelope>
```

My goal, is get all `<f>`, which contains specific string (lets say "f" for this example).
This is done, by this:

```
$result = $xml->xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'f')]]");
```

This example, returns me an array, which looks like this:

```
    array (3)
      0 => SimpleXMLElement #f4ff
         0 => "ff" (2)
      1 => SimpleXMLElement #617e
         0 => "fff" (3)
      2 => SimpleXMLElement #863a
         0 => "ffff" (4)
```

Now, this is everything all right. Now comes the problem. What I need, is value of `<d>`, if `<f>` contains "f", but I need it both in same array, like this:

```
 array (3)
      0 => SimpleXMLElement #f4ff
         0 => "dd" (2)
         1 => "ff" (2)
      1 => SimpleXMLElement #617e
         0 => "ddd" (3)
         0 => "fff" (3)
      2 => SimpleXMLElement #863a
         0 => "ffff" (4)
         0 => "ffff" (4)
```

I hope that my question is understandable. Can somebody please advice me, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I need, is value of `<d>`, if `<f>` contains `"f"`

That's easy:

```
//f[contains(. 'f')]/../d
```

> but I need it both in same array

That's not so easy. You could do this:

```
//f[contains(. 'f')]/../*[self::f or self::d]
```

which would give you a list of `<f>`s and `<d>`s where `<f>` contains `"f"`, but they would not be "grouped" into pairs. Nothing you can select with a single XPath expression would be - flat node lists is the only thing XPath can give you. Depending on how regular your input data is, this might be good enough.

If you need the "pairs" context, break up the operation. Select all `<c>` where the `<f>` contains `"f"`:

```
//c[contains(f, 'f')]
```

and for each of those, select `<f>` and `<d>` in a second step:

```
./*[self::f or self::d]
```

Note that XPath returns nodes in document order. If that's not predictable in your input, select the nodes individually instead of with a single expression.

Comment: Hello,
This would work for sure as well. I will think about it later, as it seems to be a bit more precise selecting of data. In this moment, I am going to use this instead:
`$result = $xml->xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'f')]]/parent::*");` what returns me all values from the parent...what is acceptable for me right now

Comment: `parent::*` can be shortened to `..`

Answer (score 0):

The answers is :

```
$result = $xml->xpath("//*[text()[contains(.,'f')]]/parent::*");
```

Thank all those, who tried to think about the problem. Have a nice day.